# Wall collision problems AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, hittest, flash-cs3

I'm making a game where a character walks around different rooms, but I want to keep it from going through the walls. I tried making a barrier symbol to stop it, but since the four walls enclose the character, hitTestObject returns true every time, not just when it hits the solid parts of the walls. My problem with simply using hero.x < 0 is that there are items that the character can equip that cause the hero's symbol to extend below 0. All of the symbols have been resized so I can't just get the width of the symbol within the hero's symbol. Any ideas for a better method of detecting collision? Possibly hitTestPoint, but not really sure how that would work without a huge array of points to test . . .

Comment: how about having your obstacles/walls as a single shape/movie clip and using [hitTestPoint()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()) with the shape flag(3rd argument) set to true ?

Comment: @George- I still need an array of x and y values that represents the inside border of the wall though, don't I?

Comment: have you tried this ? make a mazey shape, convert it to a movie clip, add an ENTER_FRAME handler and change the alpha of the maze clip based on the results of calling `hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true);` (e.g. `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function(e:Event):void{ maze.alpha = (maze.hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true) ? 0.5 : 1);});`(asssuming your maze clip has the instance name **maze**.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza, this determines the alpha of the maze by the overlap of the mouse and the maze. How does this help me?

Comment: If that works, it should be simple to replace the mouse coordinates with your character coordinates, right ? (or at least the coordinate furthest in the direction of it's movement / first it would hit a wall). Does this help ?

Comment: I still need a way to determine what the farthest coordinate is. Also, the wall shouldn't change in alpha based on whether the character is touching it. Isn't that what this does?

Comment: Determining the furthest coordinate should be trivial as it's based on the direction of movement: if your character's moving right, it will be character's position + it's width(right most point) for example. Do the same for the other directions( I assume you have some variables for velocity on x and y which you update on keys ). The alpha is there just as a test so you can see if this solves your problem or not. It sounds like it does and instead of changing alpha you probably want to restore the character's coordinates prior to the collision/deplete energy/etc.

Comment: The problem-solving with the alpha will certainly prove helpful, but the character width isn't related to its direction as it doesn't rotate with movement.

Comment: whether it rotates or not, it will always have a with. if you're registration is at top,left, the left most point will be 0 and right most will be the width of the object, correct ?

Comment: no, the left most point is negative and the right most point is less than the width

Comment: I did say if you're registation point is at top,left above, correct ?So in your case it looks like it isn't, it might be at the centre. if it is, left most point is -width/2 and right most is +width/2, or it could be where ever you've set it up in the flash ide but that **does not matter**, the idea is the same. Do you understand ?

Comment: the center isn't the registration point either. And it isn't symmetrical. The other half of my problem is that I'm not sure how to find the leftmost point at all

Comment: as I mentioned before, it does not matter. you have character movie clip. regardless of it's registration it has a bounding box (and therefore top, bottom, left and right) -> coordinates you can see relative to the character's parent. You use these boundiaries(top/left/right/bottom) depending on the direction(top if moving up, bottom if moving down, etc.) in the same coordinate system as your maze shape as x,y values for the hit test. Does this make sense ?

Comment: yes, but I haven't learned how to find the bounding box. getRect is giving me the numbers i am expecting

Comment: Any joy with the provided solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick demo showing the ideas I mentioned in the comment:

```
package {

    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    import flash.geom.Point;

    import flash.utils.Proxy;

    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    import flash.text.TextField;

    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    import flash.events.Event;

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class HitTestShapeTest extends Sprite {



        private var player:Player;

        private var vx:Number = 0,vy:Number = 0;

        private var speed:Number = 2;

        private var previousValidPos:Point = new Point();

        private var maze:DisplayObject;

        private var keys:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

        private var t:TextField;

        public function HitTestShapeTest() {

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

        }

        private function init(e:Event):void{

            maze = addChild(new Maze());

            player = addChild(new Player()) as Player;

            player.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;

            player.y = stage.stageHeight * .5;

            previousValidPos.x = player.x;previousValidPos.y = player.y;

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyDown);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onKeyUp);

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);     

            t = addChild(new TextField()) as TextField;   t.text = "oi";

            ExternalInterface.call("alert('ready');");

        }

        private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{

            keys[e.keyCode] = true;//this key is pressed, make that available for the update call

            t.text = ""+e.keyCode;

        }



        private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void{

            keys[e.keyCode] = null;//clear the hash map entry for the released key

            vx = vy = 0;

        }



        private function update(e:Event):void{

            //move player

            if(keys[Keyboard.LEFT] != undefined)  vx = -speed;

            if(keys[Keyboard.RIGHT] != undefined) vx =  speed;

            if(keys[Keyboard.UP] != undefined)    vy = -speed;

            if(keys[Keyboard.DOWN] != undefined)  vy =  speed;

            //update positions

            player.x += vx;

            player.y += vy;



            //get the boundary point in the direction of movement

            var bounds:Rectangle = player.getBounds(this);     //beg the character's bounds

            var testPoint:Point = new Point();
            //check which point is at the edge of the character in the direction of movement
            if(vx != 0 || vy != 0){

                if(vx < 0) testPoint.x = bounds.x;//left

                else       testPoint.x = bounds.x+bounds.width;//right

                if(vy < 0) testPoint.y = bounds.y;//top

                else       testPoint.y = bounds.y+bounds.height;//bottom

                if(vy == 0) testPoint.y = bounds.y + bounds.height * .5;//moving on x axis only, use the vertical centre on y 
                if(vx == 0) testPoint.x = bounds.x + bounds.width * .5;//moving on y axis only, use the vertical centre on x 
            }

            //check collisions

            var isHit:Boolean = maze.hitTestPoint(testPoint.x,testPoint.y,true);//check for collisions

            if(!isHit){//didn't hit anything, remember this valid position

                previousValidPos.x = player.x;

                previousValidPos.y = player.y;

            }else{//restore position because we just hit something

                player.x = previousValidPos.x;

                player.y = previousValidPos.y;

            }

            //debug graphics

            graphics.clear();

            graphics.lineStyle(1,0x990000);

            graphics.drawRect(bounds.x,bounds.y,bounds.width,bounds.height);

            graphics.drawCircle(testPoint.x,testPoint.y,5);

            player.alpha = isHit ? .5 : 1;

        }

    }

}
import flash.display.BlendMode;

import flash.events.Event;

import flash.display.Shape;

class Player extends Shape{

    public function Player(){

        init(); 

    }

    private function init():void{

        graphics.lineStyle(10);

        graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10);

        graphics.moveTo(0,10);

        graphics.lineTo(0,20);

        graphics.lineTo(-10,20);

        graphics.moveTo(0,20);

        graphics.lineTo(10,20);

        graphics.moveTo(0,20);

        graphics.lineTo(0,30);

        graphics.lineTo(-10,40);

        graphics.moveTo(0,30);

        graphics.lineTo(10,40);
        blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
    }

}

class Maze extends Shape{

    private var size:Number = 50;

    public function Maze(){

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

    }

    private function init(e:Event):void{

        graphics.beginFill(0);

        graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth,0);

        graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth,size);

        graphics.lineTo(size*4,size);

        graphics.lineTo(size*4,size*3);

        graphics.lineTo(size*3,size*3);

        graphics.lineTo(size*3,size);

        graphics.lineTo(size,size);

        graphics.lineTo(size,size*8);

        graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth,size*8);

        graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);

        graphics.lineTo(0,stage.stageHeight);

        graphics.lineTo(0,0);

        graphics.endFill();

    }

}
```

Save this as HitTestShapeTest.as and set it as the Document Class for a new .fla file to run the code, or try [this](http://wonderfl.net/c/8Rku)
Also check out the [maze tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/samples/game_1.html) on the adobe website

Comment: We don't work with package in my class, and the demo allowed the character's head to go through the bottom of the extending wall if you were travelling left or right. The only thing i really needed was getBounds, but thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: glad that was useful. the idea above is a proof of concept and not meant to be perfect. you can also pick a radius and angle(direction of movement) if you want (using `Math.atan2`). Check out the adobe demo as well. If this was useful, feel free to mark/vote

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic of maze game walls.

It uses `wall.hitTestPoint(character.x, character.y)`,

Here is an example of [maze game](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/samples/game_1.html).

Comment: but how do I compensate when the character symbol extends beyond character.x? (when the character symbol has children that are at a child x-coordinate of less than 0)
I will still get the edge of the character going through the wall.